# How to put algorithm and figure(s) side by side?

Tags: graphics, positioning, algorithms

How can I put an algorithm and figure(s) side by side?

Say,

```
XXXXXXXXXXX FIG ONE
XXXXXXXXXXX FIG ONE
XXXXXXXXXXX FIG ONE
XALGORITHMX FIG TWO 
XXXXXXXXXXX FIG TWO
```

Please, only post working solution - I am new in LaTeX. Also inform what package to include.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For correct referencing of of figures you could use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) which provides `\captionof{figure}{<caption>}`. This typesets the caption `<caption>` as that of a `figure` environment even though you have not declared the contents within a `figure` environment. This is of great help since typesetting a `figure` (or float) inside a `minipage` (a non-float) is not allowed. Additionally, the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) typesets a large body of languages verbatim and can be expanded to incorporate your own touch of formatting.

Here is a small example that shows the construction, as well as the referencing capability, if needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
%\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\medskip

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption={My first program},label=mylisting]
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  printf ("Hello World!\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \rule{0.3\textwidth}{50pt}
  \captionof{figure}{This is a figure caption.} \label{myfig1}
  \bigskip
  \rule{0.25\textwidth}{70pt}
  \captionof{figure}{This is another figure.} \label{myfig2}
\end{minipage}

\medskip

On the left is Listing~\ref{mylisting}. On the right is Figures~\ref{myfig1} and~\ref{myfig2}.

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

---

In order to use a more pseudo-code listing, you may be interested in the [`algorithmicx` package][algorithmicx-pkg]. However, for this to function fully as above, you also need the [`algorithm` package][algorithm-pkg] which defines the `algorithm` float (and associated float counter). Now you can use `\captionof{algorithm}{<caption>}`. Here is a similar example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
%\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\medskip

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\captionof{algorithm}{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{myalg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \rule{0.3\textwidth}{50pt}
  \captionof{figure}{This is a figure caption.} \label{myfig1}
  \bigskip
  \rule{0.25\textwidth}{70pt}
  \captionof{figure}{This is another figure.} \label{myfig2}
\end{minipage}

\medskip

On the left is Algorithm~\ref{myalg}. On the right is Figures~\ref{myfig1} and~\ref{myfig2}.

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided some dummy text, while [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was merely used to increase the text block size (via `margin=1in`). Dummy figures are represented by black rectangular boxes, although you would be interested in the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) for inserting your images.

Adjustment of the vertical alignment is also possible, depending on the size of algorithm or figures.

Comment: It is not a script. C is offended by such wording!

Comment: @Werner Thank you very much. It worked fine. I wanted to use algorithm environment, so instead of using \begin{lstlisting} .. \end.. I used \begin{algorithmic}[1]  {code here} \end{algorithmic}  Now, it works, only problem is I can't add caption!!
\captionof{XXXX}{test algorithm 1} works if I add, XXXX=figure. How can I use XXXX = algorithm? Possible? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Droid-Bird: See my updated answer - you need to also include the [`algorithm` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm).

Comment: @Werner, Thank you very much. Your last solution works fine too. I think, the problem is with "\documentclass{article}" and "\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}". I am using this svmult thing(this is required). So, ... Thank you very much for your help.

So, how I solved (!) it is, declared 

"\renewcommand{\tablename}{Algorithm}" Then while using, I called the caption of algo \captionof{table}{name of the table} [alas!]

By the way, have you followed, there is not horizontal line above the Algorithm, which appears when you use only one algo?

Answer (score 3):

You could either use minipages (`\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}...\end{minipage}`), which you can arrange side-by-side, or you could check out the `wrapfig` package for wrapping images by text flow generically.

Answer (score 2):

I usually put `minipage`s it in a `tabular` environment. To include figures, you will need to use `graphicx`.

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\raisebox{.1cm}{\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
Algorithm
\end{minipage}} &
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figurename.eps}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
```

You may also need to use `\raisebox` to adjust the height of one box or the other.

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\raisebox{-.1cm}{\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
Algorithm
\end{minipage}} &
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figurename.eps}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Note that TeX will complain about an overfull box using a `tabular` as-is. This is because the contents for each column has a width of `.5\textwidth` **plus** the column padding. To remove this, use `{@{}c@{}c@{}}` as the column specification. Also, your `tabular` would be indented, so you need `\noindent`.

Comment: @Werner: thanks for the comment! I've been doing this for years and have been ignoring the overfull warnings... Ha, now I know how to fix that. I forgot about the `\noindent` too - I usually set `\parindent 0pt` in my preamble for most of my reports... the other option would be to enclose the `tabular` expression in `\begin{center}...\end{center}`.