# How to decrease algorithm indent for package algpseudocode?

Tags: indentation, algorithms

I would like to save some horizontal space by changing indent space for package `algpseudocode`. How can I do that?

I think the variable I have to change is `\algorithmicindent` but I can't manage to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
Text

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\algorithmicindent{.5em}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \fbox{
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{algorithmic}[0]
      \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
          \State $a\gets b$
          \State $b\gets r$
          \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
        \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
      \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}

    \caption{Algorithm}\label{fig:alg}
  \end{subfigure}%
  }
  \quad
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \tikz\draw [fill=red!20] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \caption{tikz}\label{fig:tikz}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Both}\label{fig:both}
\end{figure}

Text \ref{fig:alg} and \ref{fig:tikz} and \ref{fig:both}

\end{document}
```

*** Edit ***

And the result of `\listfiles` is:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
algorithm.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environm
ent
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
algpseudocode.sty    
algorithmicx.sty    2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx
 caption.sty    2010/01/09 v3.1m Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2010/01/14 v3.1m caption3 kernel (AR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
subcaption.sty    2008/08/31 v1.0b Adding subcaptions (AR)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

I'm using a mac. I have installed the latex packages using macports and those are the most recent versions available there.

Comment: Note that, even though `\algorithmicindent` sounds like a length modifiable via `\setlength`, it is actually a command. Therefore, you need to use `\renewcommand{\algorithmicindent}{<len>}`. That's just the way it is...

Comment: @Werner: please, take a look at my comment on MarcoDaniel's answer.

Comment: The `algorithmic` environment of `algpseudocode` (from the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)) typesets its contents as a list which is flush with the left margin and a default item label width of `12pt`. If you have a short algorithm (with fewer than 10 lines), it may seem like there's a gap between the item and the left margin. Is this the indent you're referring to that you want removed?

Comment: @Werner: Maybe that is what I'm talking about. Please, check the example I have provided; I need the algorithm to be very close to the left side of the box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your provided example code has some mistakes. The example given in your previous question [How to put an algorithm and a tikz drawing (objects of different type) side-by-side in the same float environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40268/how-to-put-an-algorithm-and-a-tikz-drawing-objects-of-different-type-side-by-s) had no mistakes.

I will start with a short analysis of your errors.

1. First of all it seems that you haven't read any documentation. Sorry for the hard words.
2. The argument of the environment `subfigure` is the width. You want to have two `subfigure` environments besides each other. A simple calculation shows that `.5\linewidth+\quad+.5\linewidth` is greater than `\textwidth`. (`quad=\hspace{1em}`). The result is an overfull hbox
3. You set the following combination

   ```
   \fbox{
     \begin{environment}
   ```

   and this results in an extra horizontal space because you didn't comment the extra space. The correct form is

   ```
   \fbox{%
     \begin{environment}
   ```
4. You can't encapsule `subfigure` within a `\fbox`. Inside `subfigure` you can use the environment `adjustbox` to frame the `algorithmic` environment with the correct width calculation. (Used in the example.)
5. The `algorithmic` environment has no direct solution avoiding the indentation. In the example I redefined the environment itself by adding the length definition:

   ```
   \labelwidth0pt\labelsep0pt %%ADDED
   ```

   To the `ifequal` test. In this way you can use the optional argument of `algorithmic` as usual. (Thanks to Werner)

   A second approach (recommened) is to use the command `patchmd` provided by the package `etoolbox`. (For more information see the documentation). Normally the command `patchcmd` doesn't work with optional arguments. By a suggest trick (Thanks egreg) we can use the following combination:

   ```
   \expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\algorithmic\endcsname%
     {\labelwidth 0.5em}{\labelwidth0pt\labelsep0pt}{}{}
   ```

   An explanation is given in the threat [How can I use `\patchcmd` with commands with optional arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24245/how-can-i-use-patchcmd-with-commands-with-optional-arguments/24249#24249)

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\algorithmic\endcsname%
      {\labelwidth 0.5em}{\labelwidth0pt\labelsep0pt}{}{}
%\renewenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]%
%   {%
%   \edef\ALG@numberfreq{#1}%
%   \def\@currentlabel{\theALG@line}%
%   %
%   \setcounter{ALG@line}{0}%
%   \setcounter{ALG@rem}{0}%
%   %
%   \let\\\algbreak%
%   %
%   \expandafter\edef\csname ALG@currentblock@\theALG@nested\endcsname{0}%
%   \expandafter\let\csname ALG@currentlifetime@\theALG@nested\endcsname\relax%
%   %
%   \begin{list}%
%      {\ALG@step}%
%      {%
%      \rightmargin\z@%
%      \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@ \listparindent2em%
%      \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@ \parsep\z@%
%      \labelsep 0.5em \topsep 0.2em%\skip 1.2em 
%      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}%
%         {\labelwidth0pt\labelsep0pt}% %%ADDED / CHANGED
%         {\labelwidth 1.2em}%
%      \leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}% Ok. the perfect leftmargin :-))
%      \ALG@tlm\z@%
%      }%
%   \setcounter{ALG@nested}{0}%
%   \ALG@beginalgorithmic%
%   }%
%   {% end{algorithmic}
%   % check if all blocks are closed
%   \ALG@closeloops%
%   \expandafter\ifnum\csname ALG@currentblock@\theALG@nested\endcsname=0\relax%
%   \else%
%      \PackageError{algorithmicx}{Some blocks are not closed!!!}{}%
%   \fi%
%   \ALG@endalgorithmic%
%   \end{list}%
%   }%
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
Text

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\algorithmicindent{.5em}

\begin{figure}[!ht]

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,frame}
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
          \State $a\gets b$
          \State $b\gets r$
          \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
        \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
      \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
   \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Algorithm}\label{fig:alg}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \tikz\draw [fill=red!20] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \caption{tikz}\label{fig:tikz}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Both}\label{fig:both}
\end{figure}

Text \ref{fig:alg} and \ref{fig:tikz} and \ref{fig:both}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works for the indentation after the first line. Still, since I'm not using the algorithm environment, I need to get rid of the very first indent too. You can see what I am telling by putting the algorithm inside an `\fbox` with `\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}`

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. There (at the question) is the working example... (seems familiar, right? ;)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. I'll comment your statements separately: 1) True. Actually I am indeed the kind of guy who reads documentations, but currently I don't have much time to finish my document; 2) The purpose of the example was to show the space with the borders around the algorithm, I didn't look to the other things; 3) I didn't know about that. Thanks!; 4) Since I could get borders with that I thought it was ok; 5) I could not compile your example here, I am getting `...missing \item` at the `\Procedure...` line. Tomorrow I will try the other options.

Comment: Output of `\listfiles` added to the question...

Comment: @freitass: You need really an update for all your packages. What system do you use?

Comment: I have done it yesterday. I think those are the last versions of latex packages available on macports.

Comment: ...system: OS X 10.7

Comment: @freitass: With MacTeX 2010 or MacTeX 2011?

Comment: Actually not MacTeX but texlive-* packages from macports. I believe I should try MacTex 2011. I'll do it later and then I tell you what I get. Thanks!

Comment: @freitass: MacTeX is really recommend for all Mac-Systems. The installation is very simple. Please give it a try.