# Place four algorithms (algorithm2e) in a subfigure and arrange them in two rows and two columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subfloats, algorithm2e

I want to arrange four algorithms set with the `algorithm2e` package in two rows and two columns, as shown in the figure below. I've tried the `subfigure` package and have also read several related questions and answers, but have so far been unable to produce an output as shown below.

```
|------------------|       |-------------------|
|                  |       |                   |
|                  |       |                   |
|                  |       |                   |
|                  |       |                   |
|------------------|       |-------------------|
     (a) ...                       (b) ...

|------------------|       |-------------------|
|                  |       |                   |
|                  |       |                   |
|                  |       |                   |
|                  |       |                   |
|------------------|       |-------------------|
     (c) ...                       (d) ...

                  Figure 1: ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put an algorithm and a tikz drawing (objects of different type) side-by-side in the same float environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40268/how-to-put-an-algorithm-and-a-tikz-drawing-objects-of-different-type-side-by-s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `subfigure` environment from the `subcaption` package as follows.

[image: screenshot]

Note that the `subfigure` environment takes the same optional arguments that `minipage` does, so if you find yourself in a situation with different size code snippets you can use (for example) `\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}...`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\myalgorithm}{%
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\end{algorithm}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \myalgorithm
        \caption{How to write algorithms}
    \end{subfigure}% need this comment symbol to avoid overfull hbox
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \myalgorithm
        \caption{How to write algorithms}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \myalgorithm
        \caption{How to write algorithms}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \myalgorithm
        \caption{How to write algorithms}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Main caption}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option - it requires you to wrap each `algorithm` inside a minipage.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\newcommand{\myalg}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \SetAlgoLined
      \KwData{this text}
      \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
      
      initialization\;
      \While{not at end of this document}{
        read current\;
        \eIf{understand}{
          go to next section\;
          current section becomes this one\;
        }{
          go back to the beginning of current section\;
        }
      }%
      \caption{How to write algorithms}%
      \label{#1}%
    \end{algorithm}%
  \end{minipage}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \null\hfill \myalg{alg1} \hfill \myalg{alg2} \hfill\null\par \medskip
  \null\hfill \myalg{alg3} \hfill \myalg{alg4} \hfill\null
  \caption{Here are some algorithms.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the above example and for the sake of brevity, I've made the command `\myalg{<lab>}` typeset the same `algorithm` just with a different label `<lab>`. This allows you to reference the individual algorithms within the actual `figure`. Of course, you could change this to just represent (a), (b), (c) and (d).

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) provided `a3paper` and `landscape` orientation, since the algorithms were just examples (which were large). You might not require this in your regular usage. The same goes for the choice of `.4\linewidth` in your `minipage`. You could adjust this, depending on your eventual output. `minipage` also allows for an option argument specifying the vertical alignment. So, for example, if **Algorithm2** is shorter than **Algorithm 1**, you could specify `[t]` for the second so their are vertically aligned at the top.

Comment: Thanks, works great so far. What would I need to do to get "(a) caption" instead of "Algorithm 1: caption"? Moreover, when I reference an algorithm using \ref{algorithmA}, I want the reference to print the figure number, and then the letter indicating the algorithm within the figure, e.g. "see Figure 1a".

Comment: @Hermann: see my answer