# Caption below boxed algorithm2e when used as a figure?

Tags: floats, captions, algorithm2e

My desired output is similar to the example given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139305/14811), in that I want the caption below the algorithm and outside the box, except I want the algorithm included as a figure (so I use `\usepackage[figure,boxed]{algorithm2e}`).

Currently I have something like this:

[image]

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,boxed,figure]{algorithm2e}

\SetAlCapSkip{1em}

\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}

\begin{document}

  \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwInput{Parameters...}

    \KwOutput{$\emptyset$}

    \If{Condition}
    {
      Do something \;
    }
    \caption{Algoritm test...}
  \end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Would ths help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49337/34618

Comment: @Jesse I think that would be fine too. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to go is to set the algorithm as a non-floating object (use `H` instead of `h`) and use a normal `figure` environment instead of the option `figure` when loading `algorithm2e`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,boxed]{algorithm2e}

%\SetAlCapSkip{1em}

\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwInput{Parameters...}

    \KwOutput{$\emptyset$}

    \If{Condition}
    {
      Do something \;
    }
  \end{algorithm}
  \caption{Algoritm test...}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: does it need `!H` or just `H`?

Comment: @adifferentben just `H`

Comment: As a supplement: the `!H` in `\begin{algorithm}[!H]` in my case (using `algorithmicx`) raises an error `Not in outer par mode`. `H` works well.

Comment: This does not work for a twocolumn environment.

Comment: Maybe this should be a new question. But I find placing the figure correctly (with the caption nicely spaced as you do here) much easier when I put the algorithm in a figure like you do here. But I want the caption to read Algorithm 1 and use the algorithm counter. Is this possible?