# multiple algorithm2e algorithms in two column documents

Tags: floats, subfloats, two-column, algorithm2e

I tried this example [Place four algorithms (algorithm2e) in a subfigure and arrange them in two rows and two columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40365/place-four-algorithms-algorithm2e-in-a-subfigure-and-arrange-them-in-two-rows) on two column documents. It doesn't work. The error message is

```
! LaTeX Error: [H] in two columns mode is not allowed for algorithms.
```

Is there anyway to go?

The code example is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\newcommand{\myalgorithm}{%
\begin{algorithm*}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\end{algorithm*}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \myalgorithm
        \caption{How to write algorithms}
    \end{subfigure}% need this comment symbol to avoid overfull hbox
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \myalgorithm
        \caption{How to write algorithms}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \myalgorithm
        \caption{How to write algorithms}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \myalgorithm
        \caption{How to write algorithms}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Main caption}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) provides its own `[H]` float parameter, which sidesteps setting its contents as a float. However, in `twocolumn` mode, it produces an error.  I'm not sure why. You can avoid this by setting `\@latex@error` to `\@gobble` temporarily. Using your example, I've added a `\removelatexerror` macro inside a `\begingroup`...`\endgroup`. More specifically, the definition

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

is placed inside a group, inside `\myalgorithm`:

```
\newcommand{\myalgorithm}{%
\begingroup
\removelatexerror% Nullify \@latex@error
\begin{algorithm*}[H]
%...
\end{algorithm*}
\endgroup}
```

Also, since you're spreading the 4 algorithms across both columns, it's best to use `figure*` rather than `figure`:

[image]

Obviously you won't be using `\myalgorithm` in your actual document. You could just place `\removelatexerror` inside each of the `subfigure` environments.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues...

I simply removed [H] from the code as below.

```
\begin{algorithm*}[H]
```

to

```
\begin{algorithm*}
```

Then the issue solved.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It works if we remove [H]. Otherwise, * does not work.