# pgfplots and subfigure

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats

I'm using Springer LNCS template to create a paper, so that I can't use `subcaption`
Using `subfigure` with pgfplots results in no aligning at all. [image]

The code I use to draw plots:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfigure{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    
    ybar = 0pt,
    scale = 0.6,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
    xticklabels={Bayes, Tree, kNN, SVM},
    xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 100,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
]
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 68) (2, 70) (3, 67) (4, 66) 
};
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 70)     (2, 71) (3, 72) (4, 68)
};

\legend{unmodified, modified}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\subfigure{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    scale = 0.6,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
    xticklabels={Bayes, Tree, kNN, SVM},
    xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 100,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
]
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 68) (2, 70) (3, 67) (4, 67) 
};
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 68)     (2, 70) (3, 70) (4, 68)
};

\legend{unmodified, modified}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\subfigure{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    scale = 0.6,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
    xticklabels={Bayes, Tree, kNN, SVM},
    xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 100,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
]
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 69) (2, 67) (3, 72) (4, 68) 
};
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 70)     (2, 70) (3, 73) (4, 69)
};

\legend{unmodified, modified}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Genuineness}
\end{figure}
```

How can I fix it and display all the plots in one row?

**EDIT** Thanks to @percusse the issue was in empty lines. Now it looks okay.

Comment: why can't you use `subcaption`? Notice that in any case don't use `subfigure` but at least `subfig`. And remove the empty lines in between they mean paragraphs

Comment: @percusse Thank you very much! Indeed, the issue was connected with empty lines. 
I found answers on TeX exchange that LLNCS template doesn't support `subcaption` package, so I have to use another.

Comment: Apparently I did something similar in a previous life using subcaption and llcns http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61824/put-two-algorithm-side-by-side

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should avoid `subfigure` that has been obsolete for more than 15 years:

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

is the call you should do.

I'm not sure what you need subfloats for, as you don't use subcaptions. So I'll add empty subcaptions for getting just the letters.

Notes:

1. you shouldn't have blank lines between the subfloats that you want side by side
2. you shouldn't have blank lines in the `tikzpicture` environments
3. this particular example would end up with an overfull line, so I left the third subfigure below the other two (just adding a blank line

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar = 0pt,
    scale = 0.6,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
    xticklabels={Bayes, Tree, kNN, SVM},
    xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 100,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
]
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 68) (2, 70) (3, 67) (4, 66) 
};
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 70)     (2, 71) (3, 72) (4, 68)
};
\legend{unmodified, modified}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    scale = 0.6,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
    xticklabels={Bayes, Tree, kNN, SVM},
    xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 100,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
]
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 68) (2, 70) (3, 67) (4, 67) 
};
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 68)     (2, 70) (3, 70) (4, 68)
};
\legend{unmodified, modified}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    scale = 0.6,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
    xticklabels={Bayes, Tree, kNN, SVM},
    xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 100,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
]
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 69) (2, 67) (3, 72) (4, 68) 
};
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 70)     (2, 70) (3, 73) (4, 69)
};
\legend{unmodified, modified}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Genuineness}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]